# Laravel horizon queued jobs fails with MaxAttemptsExceededException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-horizon

I dispatch jobs to do some work on my horizon queue. It appears the same jobs are always failing with 60s runtime, which to me looks like a timeout issue:

[image]

I dispatch around 10 jobs via a cron schedule, and these 4 are always failing.

This is my `config/horizon.php` (just the interesting parts):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    'waits' => [
        'redis:default' => 60,
    ],

    'memory_limit' => 512,

    'defaults' => [
        'my-app-queue' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['default'],
            'balance' => 'auto',
            'minProcesses' => 1,
            'maxProcesses' => 1,
            'balanceMaxShift' => 1,
            'balanceCooldown' => 3,
            'memory' => 512,
            'tries' => 3,
            'nice' => 0,
            'timeout' => 300,
        ],
    ],

    'environments' => [
        'production' => [
            'my-app-queue' => [
                'maxProcesses' => 10,
            ],
        ],

        'local' => [
            'my-app-queue' => [
                'maxProcesses' => 10,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

As you can see, I have set a timeout of 300 seconds, but the job always failing at 60 second mark.

I start the horizon queue processor in my docker container with this entrypoint command: `php /path/to/artisan horizon`

To debug the issue, I instantiated the job class manually to see where it is failing like this:

```
    $test = new DownloadBlockedIPFeed(8);
    $test->handle();
    exit('Done');
```

This does seem to be taking longer than 60 seconds, but it does complete.

So my question is - how do you properly set the timeout for laravel horizon?

I am using laravel 8.x and latest version of the horizon package.

Comment: Sounds like it's the PHP timeout being hit, not the horizon configuration.

Comment: doesn't php-cli has `max_execution_time` set to `-1`? the jobs should be executing in cli and inheriting no executing time limit. i'll double check just to be sure.

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#job-expirations-and-timeouts try adding a `retry_after` with a value of 300 as well

Comment: If your job classes have a timeout specified, those take priority over Horizon’s default, regardless if the class’ timeout is greater or less than Horizon’s default.

Comment: @Latheesan Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

It may also be the balance strategy. I've found that If I set the 'balance' option to 'auto', it gives the MaxAttemptsExceededException errors. changing it to 'simple' or 'false' seems to be the solution.

Not sure if this is a bug, but I don't think this is expected behavior either. I've seen jobs that where executed (logging in the handle method of the job) but killed off in the middle for retry.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value for `--timeout=` in the spawned `horizon:supervisor` process. If this is 60 seconds, adjust the `timeout` value in `config/horizon.php`.

Also check `retry_after` in `config/queue.php`.